# error while passing a php variable's value having _ as second parameter onclick to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

This is my php code

```
foreach($resource as $res) {    
    $PDF = $res->res_link; 
    $pdfname = $res->$res_name; (which is Dimesional_analysis) 

    echo "<a class='pdflink' href='#' onClick=OpenPdf('$PDF','$pdfname');><div class='txt'><table class='txt-in'><tr><td>$icon</td><td> $temp </tr></table></div></a>";
}
```

and my onclick javascript code

```
           function OpenPdf(pdf,pdfname) {
            some functionality;
            }
```

However, on clicking the link it is showing "unterminated string literal". however, when the pdfname has no underscore, that is if I give like `$pdfname = 'Dimension'` it is working fine.Hope someone will help me solve this. Thanks.

Comment: try ('%"PDF"%','%"pdfname"%');

Comment: Hi please send a "some functionality;" inside of OpenPdf function

Comment: You could try converting the name of the PDF using [HTML-entities](http://no1.php.net/htmlentities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always look at the generated HTML:

```
<a class='pdflink' href='#' onClick=OpenPdf('something','Dimensional_analysis');>
```

That doesn't look valid to me :p It's certainly vulnerable to problems.

Try this: (newlines added for readability)

```
echo '<a class="pdflink" data-pdf="'.htmlspecialchars($PDF).'"
    data-pdfname="'.htmlspecialchars($pdfname).'"
    onClick="OpenPdf(this.getAttribute(\'data-pdf\'),
                                       this.getAttribute(\'data-pdfname\'));">';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "<a class='pdflink' href='#' onClick=OpenPdf('".$PDF."','".$pdfname."');><div class='txt'><table class='txt-in'><tr><td>$icon</td><td> $temp </tr></table></div></a>";
```